# HTML iFrame contents

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

When I access the iframe with a=window.frames["iframe"] it says that a is a DOMWindow.
But when I try to access document it says undefined, but when I use top it refers back to it self. It's like the iframe only have itself as a property.
When i access it trough document.getElementById("iframe") it identifies itself as HTMLIFrame, but the problem still exists, this is really weird and i need help.

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").getDocument
document.getElementById("iframe").getDocument()
document.getElementById("iframe").html.body
document.getElementById("iframe").body
document.getElementById("iframe").document.getElementById("btag")
```

and many more combinations.

I seriously do not know why it acts this way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access either the `contentWindow` or `contentDocument` depending on the browser.

I've done some light testing and it seems `.document` isn't working (I'm in chrome) this may be a better solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/sTkVR/4/

document.frames['frmID'] returns the equivalent as `contentWindow` or `contentDocument` which is why it says `DOMWindow`

Comment: If using jQuery can simply access iframe content with .contents() http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: Okay, apparently chrome uses contentWindow intead of contentDocument but the problem i described still exists.

Comment: Error log might help :)<br>

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///media/LEXAR/dialog.html from frame with URL file:///media/LEXAR/win.htm. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
window.js:163
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'getElementById

else if ( typeof(iframeEl.contentWindow) !== "undefined" ) { // IE win
    var el = iframeEl.contentWindow.getElementById('name'); //<-- line 163
}

Comment: You cannot access the `document` property of a window of a different origin.

Comment: Does that mean i can't access the html contents of the iframe?

Comment: Yes. If the content of the iframe originated on a different protocol, domain or port, you cannot. It would pose a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

The `window.frames` property is actually a circular reference to the window itself.

```
window.frames === window
window.frames === window.self
```

`DOMWindow` is an Array-like structure in that it has a `length` property and properties of numerical keys.

The `window.frames` property exists for the sole reason of providing access to frames by their numerical indexes such as `window.frames[0]` or just `frames[0]`. You could, of course, access the given frame as `window[0]` but that just does not look correct.

Elements of this pseudo-Array (accessed as `frames[index]`) are instances of `DOMWindow` (in case of iframes, they point to `iframe.contentWindow`) and you can access their `document` properties if they have a common origin with the current window (i.e. same protocols, domains and ports).

If you name a frame or an iframe (with an `id` attribute), they are (at least in WebKit-based browsers) mapped to properties of their owner window. In case of an `iframe`, the property points to the `<iframe>` element rather than to its `contentWindow` property.

```
// <iframe name="a">
frames['a'] === window['a'] === document.getElementById('a')
```